# get data from model with condition laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have **Users_group** model in my Laravel project.

**Code:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users_group extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users_groups';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_id', 'group_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function getGroupData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Group','id','group_id');
    }
}
```

And when I want to get data from this model I use this my custom method:

```
$data = App\Users_group ::get();
```

It's working great

I want to get the data from model with condition not like this:

```
$data = App\Users_group::where('group_id','>',5)->get();
```

I need to put the condition inside the model file thats make the model return the data everytime I call `User_group::get()` return it when condition inside the model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) to achieve this. Query scopes allow you to add a global constraint to a model.

In your case, you could add the following boot method to your model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('groupOver5', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('group_id', '>', 5);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one in by using `scope`    in model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users_group extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users_groups';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'user_id', 'group_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];



     public function scopeGetGroupData($query,$value,$opertor = '>')
        {
            return $query->where('group_id', $opertor, $value);
        }

}
```

> get data in controller like this u can pass also parameter in method

```
App\Users_group::GetGroupData($value)->get();
```